# T-SQL: How to replace spaces in a string except if they are after a specific character

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, parsing, casting

The situation is as follows:

We have action logs in our database triggered by user events, that saves the events in varchar but in xml format. In some cases the name of the attributes contains spaces like this one:

```
<UNITDETAILUPDATE NEWUNIT TYPE="DUW 30 01" OLDFAULT_CIRC="HWS" NEWFAULT_CIRC="HWS" OLDOUTGOING R-STATE="R3C" />
```

I would like to eliminate the spaces from the names of the attributes before parsing to xml(because this way it is not possible of course :))
As you can see there are multiple occurences in the string. A great solution would be something like only replacing the spaces where there is no " character before them, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Any ideas?

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you change logging to not use spaces for attributes? If you have a list of known attributes then just do some replaces
replace([column1],'NEWUNIT TYPE','NEWUNIT_TYPE')

Comment: There is a huge amount of logs, and attributes(I don't know the exact names for all of them :( ) and I need historical data now. This would solve the issue for future logs, but I have to get the data from the existing logs too. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for good spaces and save them with a placeholder

```
Declare @var varchar(100) = '<UNITDETAILUPDATE NEWUNIT TYPE="DUW 30 01" OLDFAULT_CIRC="HWS" NEWFAULT_CIRC="HWS" OLDOUTGOING R-STATE="R3C" />'

Select @var = replace(@var,'" ','"|")
```

Then remove the spaces

```
Select @var = replace(@var,' ','_')
```

Then put the good spaces back

```
Select @var = replace(replace(@var,'|',' '),'UNITDETAILUPDATE_','UNITDETAILUPDATE ')
```

This could be combined into one ugly replace so that it could be selected across a table. You would probably need to placehold the spaces inside the quotations. Regex is not supported in SQL but sometimes it could be used with 'like'

Answer (score 1):

For a high-performing set-based solution you can grab a copy of [ngrams8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) and do this:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(1000)   = '<UNITDETAILUPDATE NEWUNIT TYPE="DUW 30 01" OLDFAULT_CIRC="HWS" NEWFAULT_CIRC="HWS" OLDOUTGOING R-STATE="R3C" />';

select newString = 
(
  select 
    case when token = ' ' and position > space1 and isQuoted = 0 and p.c <> '"'
    then '' else token end
  from
  (
    select ng.*, sum(case when token = '"' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by position)%2
    from dbo.ngrams8k(@string, 1) ng
  ) x(position, token, isQuoted)
  cross join  (values (charindex(' ', @string))) v(space1)
  cross apply (values (substring(@string, position-1,1))) p(c)
  order by position
  for xml path(''), type
).value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)');
```

**Results**

```
<UNITDETAILUPDATE NEWUNITTYPE="DUW 30 01" OLDFAULT_CIRC="HWS" NEWFAULT_CIRC="HWS" OLDOUTGOINGR-STATE="R3C" />
```

If you have a SQL Server 2017 you can use string_agg like with ngrams8k like this:

```
select newString = string_agg(
    case when token = ' ' and position > space1 and isQuoted = 0 
      and substring(@string, position-1,1) <> '"' then '' else token end,'')
from
(
  select ng.*, sum(case when token = '"' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by position)%2
  from dbo.ngrams8k(@string, 1) ng
) x(position, token, isQuoted)
cross join  (values (charindex(' ', @string))) v(space1)
cross apply (values (substring(@string, position-1,1))) p(c);
```

Comment: Hi, nice solution, but I doubt, that this would be any faster than mine. The linked `ngrams8k()` function uses a tally table to step through the string and uses `SUBSTRING` to return a derived table character by character. The re-concatenation with `FOR XML PATH` produces quite some overhead too. For the OP I hope, that this is a *one-time-action*. Performance might be not so important... Anyway, +1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

This "Xml" is awfully bad...

The following approach won't be fast. If you need this more often, you might use another language or tool.

This solutions uses a recursive CTE, which is a hidden RBAR, to build ab the string again, charachter by character, checking for "within quotes":

```
DECLARE @BadXml NVARCHAR(MAX)='<UNITDETAILUPDATE NEWUNIT TYPE="DUW 30 01" OLDFAULT_CIRC="HWS" NEWFAULT_CIRC="HWS" OLDOUTGOING R-STATE="R3C" />';

WITH recCTE
AS
(
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@BadXml,'" ','"$'))) AS TheString
          ,1 AS CurrentPos
          ,CAST('<' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS BuildNew
          ,-1 AS IsFirstBlank 
          ,-1 AS QuotOpen

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.TheString
          ,r.CurrentPos+1
          ,r.BuildNew + CASE WHEN chr=' ' AND r.IsFirstBlank=1 AND r.QuotOpen=-1 THEN '_' ELSE chr END
          ,CASE WHEN r.IsFirstBlank=-1 AND chr=' ' THEN 1 ELSE r.IsFirstBlank END
          ,CASE WHEN chr='"' THEN r.QuotOpen * (-1) ELSE r.QuotOpen END
    FROM recCTE AS r 
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(r.TheString,r.CurrentPos+1,1)) AS A(chr)
    WHERE r.CurrentPos<LEN(r.TheString)

)
SELECT TOP 1 IsFirstBlank,QuotOpen, CAST(REPLACE(BuildNew,'"$','" ') AS XML) AS TheXml
FROM recCTE
ORDER BY LEN(BuildNew) DESC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

The result

```
IsFirstBlank    QuotOpen    TheXml
1               -1          <UNITDETAILUPDATE NEWUNIT_TYPE="DUW 30 01" OLDFAULT_CIRC="HWS" NEWFAULT_CIRC="HWS" OLDOUTGOING_R-STATE="R3C" />
```

Take away the CAST to xml, the `TOP 1` and the `ORDER BY` to see how it works.